# How to clean restart R in VS Code?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, how to clean restart R?

Comment: Is there a difference between restart and clean restart?

Comment: I just kill the terminal and open a new one.

Comment: Thanks, @Maël! By clean restart I mean something equivalent to RStudio's `Ctrl + Shift + F10`. That is: Restarting R without any package loaded nor any variable in the workspace.

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/randy3k/radian/issues/296.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Maël: from that, I have found out that another alternative to killing the terminal seems to be `startup::restart()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `system("R")` to restart R without any package loaded and variable in the workspace.

```r
library(dplyr)
d = tibble(1)
## A tibble: 1 × 1
#    `1`
#  <dbl>
#1     1

system("R")

> d
Error: object 'd' not found
> mutate
Error: object 'mutate' not found
```

Comment: @PaulS are you sure this actually kills the previously running R session? It seems like it would just open a subprocess but not necessarily free up RAM from the other session.

Comment: Thanks, @SamR, for your feedback! Maybe you are right. How can one check it out? I am running Linux.

Comment: @PaulS you could run `top` in a bash shell to look at the PID of the first R session, then run `system("R")` in your R terminal, then run top again (in the shell) and see if the original PID exists. Alternatively, quit the second R session with `q()` and see if it returns to the shell or the previous session.

Comment: You are absolutely right, @SamR: After having run `system("R")`, with running `quit()` I return to the previous session, with the previous loaded variables on the global environment. So, the best way is to kill the terminal, as you suggest. Thanks a lot!